# Interest in looking into adding the YouTube viewer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Adding a feature to a site requires some investigation into community interest and to use cases. Here's a [successful example](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2224/5334). In that case the feature was MathJax and the issue was load time and server overhead or something to that effect. It took about 16 months!

I'm wondering if there is interest in adding the ability to view in-line YouTube videos to posts here in Astronomy SE? There is a certain level of parity between Space SE and Astronomy SE and I'm always surprised when embedded videos show there but don't show here. [Latest example, probably not the best use case though](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29115/7982)

I'm curious if there is any interest in looking into adding the YouTube viewer here. Since it seems it can take a long time to do this, consider that we're talking about how we envision the future of the site and the field of Astronomy, and the astronomical data and content available in the future, and not only experience in the past.

[image]

Comment: @called2voyage We can turn this on but it'd really help if we had some great examples of times this would be beneficial to the answers on the site. There is always some concern with abuse and a lot of dead links since YouTube sometimes unexpectedly removes videos. This can be damaging to your content if the answer relies only on the video with no additional content, the answer becomes useless if the video dies.

Comment: @Catija We would not allow video-only or video-reliant answers. Videos would be for supplementary purposes only, as described in my answer below. We can definitely compile a list of example cases, if that would be helpful.

Comment: @Catija I started a community wiki answer of example cases below. You can see there are already quite a few.

Comment: @Catija I've added to [c2v's list](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/614/7982).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** It has now been enabled on the site.

---

I'm going to hazard a guess that since this has a net score of 10 currently, which is an ample amount for Astronomy meta, the community is generally interested in this.

I could see it being useful in some cases as a visual aid for things that can be kind of hard to envision from a textual description, especially where a novice might not know what is being described in technical terms and a simpler explanation would require a lengthy detour from the main text.

Comment: If you update to mention this has been implemented (yay!) I can accept.

Answer (score 2):

Examples where YouTube viewer would be helpful:

- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/35572/6
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32069/6
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/11043/6
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/281/6
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/34531/6
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33262/6
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33391/6
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/1094/6

---

For at least half of these posts I would not have used the embedded video player because users here enjoy a clean look, but for some of them I've had to resort to screenshots or GIFs of the videos which is not ideal. In those cases an embedded viewer in a post would have been preferable. I haven't checked all of these but out of about 20 I did check I only found one that ESA had removed from their YouTube channel (the ESPRESSO spectrometer for some reason)

- [V838 Monocerotis "light-echo" images morphed into nice video, but why so few original images?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14660) vid: [In Space, Echoes of Light | Out There | The New York Times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-KEE_yvim0)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32534 vid: [Missions we Lost When Apollo was Cancelled](https://youtu.be/QUHyDnMS5oo?t=277)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/35638 vid: [Tracing the 2017 Solar Eclipse](https://youtu.be/MJgXaqW3md8)
- [How deep is the "A" Fraunhofer line in the solar spectrum? Is it from the Sun's or Earth's atmosphere?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18032) vid: [NASA | Seeing Photosynthesis from Space](https://youtu.be/1XilneV3cJI)
- [When will the next transit of Earth be visible from Mars? Was the last one really on May 11, 1984?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26177) vid: ['Transit Of Earth' by Arthur C. Clarke read by himself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csxT8Y9MaSs)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29608 vid: [Near-Earth Asteroid 3753 Cruithne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsHsYjuudVo)
- [What exactly are infrared dark clouds and what is the significance of the orientation of their magnetic fields?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34067) vid: [Why NASA's SOFIA Telescope On A Plane is "Perfectly Balanced"](https://youtu.be/eNjHvbqYkB0?t=604)
- [How exactly will DESI simultaneously capture individual spectra from 5,000 galaxies using optical fibers?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33804) vid: [A 2dF night at the Anglo-Australian Telescope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOtkI4HYzTk)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/27643 vid: [NASA Jets Chase The Total Solar Eclipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0GNqlGNZkI)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33335 vid: [How to capture star spectra in your backyard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fv5fFSacVO8)
- [What is the LSST's plan to address frequent satellite trails in data?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33540) vid: [Spy Satellites (from Deep Sky Videos)](https://youtu.be/ETt_l0MiXAo?t=100)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29658 vid: [What Rock Star Brian May Discovered About Interplanetary Dust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jdb-DPjHEuw)
- [How do radio astronomers avoid having their receivers burned out by ground-imaging radar from satellites?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34872) vid: [AAS 235 Press Conference: Astronomy Confronts Satellite Constellations](https://youtu.be/QM1eh7nq24I?t=2040)
- ***PLAYS!***  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/35967/7982 vid: [SpaceX Starlink satellites train seen from earth - Strange lights in the sky](https://youtu.be/l58nWIvyYs0)
- [What can be learned from, or noted in this LIGO Orrery video?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28610) vid: [LIGO Orrery](https://youtu.be/gmmD72cFOU4)
- [How are all the intermediate images between the "lensed" and "unlensed" endpoints of this video generated?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38549) vid: [SPT0418-47: lensed view to reconstructed view](https://youtu.be/Nvy_wUvTI2E)
- [What experiment does this "Tracing the History of Starlight" video try to explain?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28814) vid: [Tracing the History of Starlight with NASA's Fermi Mission](https://youtu.be/V-v0DwNa194)
- [Stellar nurseries in the "Shedding New Light on the Whirlpool Galaxy" video](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29457) vid: [Shedding New Light on the Whirlpool Galaxy](https://youtu.be/M8XQFVyYfL4)
- [How did they make a video of the center of the galaxy, and what is it exactly that's flashing there?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28940) vid: [ESOcast 173: First Successful Test of Einstein’s General Relativity Near Supermassive Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if2opecmev8)
- [Questions about Hubble's brand new view of an interstellar comet (video)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33699) vid: [Hubble's New Image of Interstellar Object](https://youtu.be/JG9x6tkf8mg)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32021 vid: [LIGO Orrery](https://youtu.be/gmmD72cFOU4)
- [How long can afterglow last after a fireball?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23021) vid: [Perseid Meteor Shower - Mojave Desert, California](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ08miQEa_k)
- [What cluster of stars is this with a "dark donut" to one side?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33539) vid: [Spy Satellites (from Deep Sky Videos)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETt_l0MiXAo)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/34916 vid: [DKIST first light high-resolution video of solar granules](https://youtu.be/tZpTJzVtKHw) and [DKIST First light video of solar granulation (wide angle)](https://youtu.be/YcjGngsLpS4)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28152/7982 vid: [I made a CAMERA LENS with an ICEBERG](https://youtu.be/jWvwt3mCu68)
- [What is causing this strange shimmering pattern of light during a total solar eclipse?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27221) vid: [Space Station Transiting 2017 ECLIPSE, My Brain Stopped Working - Smarter Every Day 175](https://youtu.be/lepQoU4oek4)
- [What is the large astronomical instrument shown in this 1918 eclipse expedition photo?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21760) vid: [100% Total Solar Eclipse](https://youtu.be/5GIjfkFucSs)
- [Questions about amateur astrophotographer Nik Szymanek's telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33541) vid: [Spy Satellites (from Deep Sky Videos)](https://youtu.be/ETt_l0MiXAo?t=100)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32113 vid: [NASA'S NICER Does the Space Station Twist](https://youtu.be/kk0ry3_R2pE) and [Unlocking Secrets of Neutron Stars with NICER](https://youtu.be/IOEPDf2DYNM)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29949 vid: [SpaceX Crew Dragon Returns from Space Station](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVEBO6Zuppk)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33096 vid: [Earth from Himawari-8 satellite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WunH8bPPhP8)
- [What does this "web on the surface of the Sun" image reflect? What does 789 nm show us?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34915) vid: [DKIST first light high-resolution video of solar granules](https://youtu.be/tZpTJzVtKHw) and [DKIST First light video of solar granulation (wide angle)](https://youtu.be/YcjGngsLpS4)
- [Why did the distribution of asteroids discovered in 2010 have a radial modulation?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25736) vid: [Asteroid Discovery - 1970-2015 - 8K resolution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKKg4lZ_o-Y)
- [Why is the Nancy Grace Roman Space Telescope (WFIRST) coronagraph considered "beyond-state-of-the-art"?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36271) vid: [NASA's Nancy Grace Roman Space Telescope: Broadening Our Cosmic Horizons](https://youtu.be/jPq2VVPjk_U?t=90)
- [Which telescope's model is being shown to Albert Einstein in this file footage? What event might this be?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27319) vid: [Why does time pass?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKKbkS_LOu4)
- [Why does the closest approach of star S2 to Sgr A* not appear to be near the focus of its elliptical orbit?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35836) vid: [The star S2 makes a close approach to the black hole at the centre of the Milky Way](https://youtu.be/wstMu4ZndM8)
- [Why are Delta Aquariids "for the southern hemisphere" while the Perseids are "for the north"?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/37122) vid: [How to spot Comet NEOWISE, plus the largest 3D map of the Universe | Night Sky News July 20](https://youtu.be/RbZ13TEHuOs?t=328)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29493 vid: [Footage: Chang’e-4 making soft landing on the Moon’s far side](https://youtu.be/jyjyf4ANGIo)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/30078 vid: [Moon Setting Behind Teide Volcano](https://youtu.be/afHfMMC-MJE)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/35408 vid: [lagrange points animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z52WWLE8bBo)
- [How might WFIRST help us better understand dark energy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25060) vid: [WFIRST: The Best of Both Worlds](https://youtu.be/LbJpVHMV1m4)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33695 vid: [Hubble's New Image of Interstellar Object](https://youtu.be/JG9x6tkf8mg)
- [How did TESS scientists choose which stars to observe at a "2 minute cadence" in each field?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25890) vid: [Transiting Exoplanet Survey Satellite (TESS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpViVEO-ymc)
- [At what latitude could Orion's belt and Aldebaran be ~10 degrees above the horizon at the same time?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28189) vid: [The Mystery That Keeps Neil deGrasse Tyson Up At Night](https://youtu.be/TgA2y-Bgi3c?t=465)
- [How do they measure sub-centimeter wave height on a moon of Saturn?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28816) vid: [The Mandelbrot Set](https://youtu.be/MwjsO6aniig?t=776)
- [What exactly is the relationship between the orbits of Neptune's moons Naiad and Thalassa?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33960) vid: [Neptune Moon Dance (Naiad and Thalassa)](https://youtu.be/e0CRw7-S08U)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33753 vid: [testing Hoya UV & IR Cut Filter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrpNkvaVCdI)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/24043 vid: [Precession of the earth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlVgEoZDjok)
- [Why is the opening in the Anglo-Australian Telescope's dome so small?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29116) vid: [A 2dF night at the Anglo-Australian Telescope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOtkI4HYzTk)
- [Are there any ways in which the light time difference between the center and the edge of the solar disk is noticeable?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29486) vid: [New space discovery has astronomers buzzing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubYhcVWmrbE)
- [How will nearby galaxies some day expand beyond our horizon? (Neil deGrasse Tyson)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28188) vid: [The Mystery That Keeps Neil deGrasse Tyson Up At Night](https://youtu.be/TgA2y-Bgi3c?t=427)
- [Why does the solar wind switch to flowing straight by the time it reaches Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34173) vid: [5 New Discoveries from NASA's Parker Solar Probe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ReQAUocScw0)
- [Basic explanation of baryon acoustic oscillations; what if anything is actually oscillating?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/37094) vid: [The eBOSS 3D map of the Universe](https://youtu.be/KJJXbcf8kxA) and [SDSS releases largest 3D map of the universe ever created](https://youtu.be/TKiYOnsE8Y4)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/31650 vid: [173 Kiloton Explosion Over Bering Sea Was Asteroid Breaking Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpaxvjFh-qA)
- [How do magnetic fields mess with astronomers' observations?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38522) vid: [The biggest black hole burp, a wobbly Milky Way & Betelgeuse is brighter | Night Sky News March 2020](https://youtu.be/1cw2jJv3Wr8?t=565)
- [What allows WFIRST to have similar resolution to Hubble over a 100x larger solid angle?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/25066) vid: [WFIRST: The Best of Both Worlds](https://youtu.be/LbJpVHMV1m4)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32605 vid: [ESOcast 173: First Successful Test of Einstein’s General Relativity Near Supermassive Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if2opecmev8)
- [How did they make a video of the center of the galaxy, and what is it exactly that's flashing there?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28940) vid: [ESOcast 173: First Successful Test of Einstein’s General Relativity Near Supermassive Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if2opecmev8)
- [Can the interferometer called "Gravity" measure "a few centimeters on the Moon"?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35837) vid: [Interview with Reinhard Genzel (in English)](https://youtu.be/OgwrnLOXhNA?t=531)
- [How does this telescope work, and what is it for?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27457) vid: [How Large Can a Telescope Be?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wOFAkggSiU)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20034 vid: [A Day Over the UK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmtejbrFte0)
- [What do "star noise" and "sky noise" refer to for TESS (Transiting Exoplanet Survey Satellite)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/22082) vid: [Transiting Exoplanet Survey Satellite (TESS)](https://youtu.be/mpViVEO-ymc)
- [Why were two galaxies named "The Sagittarius Galaxy"? Is this common?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36354) vid: [Dwarf galaxy collisions make stars form in Milky Way](https://youtu.be/uNnPRrEvfhs)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33401 vid: [Tracing the 2017 Solar Eclipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJgXaqW3md8)
- [Does Arecibo's secondary optics compensate aberrations when viewing farther away from vertical?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28508) vid: [Arecibo Uncut: Under the Dish with Phil Perillat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjDJLNubKKw)
- [How can I hear (or at least detect) a pulsar at home?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34348) vid: [Using Relativistic Raytracing &X-Rays To See Detail on Surface Of Neutron Star](https://youtu.be/bwZHzKnEEs4)
- [Why does the neutral hydrogen velocity have this characteristic behavior in the galactic plane?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18831) vid: [A new all-sky survey of neutral hydrogen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2mgpsTFuV8)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/34531 vid: [The Harvard Computers - Origins of the Stellar Classification System](https://youtu.be/of5wnvGC6aY) and [The Glass Ceiling and The Glass Universe](https://youtu.be/F0I0iv8nEDM) and [Dava Sobel: The Glass Universe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlEuezOSsx0)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32786 vid: [Imaging the Unseen: Taking the First Picture of a Black Hole - Katie Bouman - 6/7/2019](https://youtu.be/glfON286APE?t=1545)
- [How far have stars been seen beyond the center of the Milky Way?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32794) vid: [ESOcast 173: First Successful Test of Einstein’s General Relativity Near Supermassive Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if2opecmev8)
- [Would an extremely bright star produce same kind of shadow band effect as seen in solar eclipses just before totality?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27226) vid: [Space Station Transiting 2017 ECLIPSE, My Brain Stopped Working - Smarter Every Day 175](https://youtu.be/lepQoU4oek4)
- [How was Earth's "quasi-satellite" 2016 HO3 "first spotted" and it's orbit determined?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16303) vid: [Asteroid 2016 HO3 - Earth's Constant Companion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbbAnVU4rmY) and [The Trajectory of the Strange Object 2016 HO3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mVfE_qmQAg)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36012 vid: [The Glass Ceiling and The Glass Universe](https://youtu.be/F0I0iv8nEDM) and [Dava Sobel: The Glass Universe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlEuezOSsx0)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/31825 vid: [The Equivalence Principle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8iP5WsiSbc)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29115 vid: [A 2dF night at the Anglo-Australian Telescope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOtkI4HYzTk)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29973 vid: [Rough cut video of AMC-9 satellite on Friday night](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ebIAUjFfZM) and [Telkom-1 Satellite Debris Incident](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FXX1kSNljU)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/25027 vid: [Asteroids In Resonance With Jupiter](https://youtu.be/yt1qPCiOq-8) and [Asteroid Discovery - 1980-2012 - UHDTV](https://youtu.be/xJsUDcSc6hE)
- [What telescope is this, and how does it work?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21198) vid: [Amazing piece of metal (speculum)](https://youtu.be/4ESW_NTIhBM)
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18525 vid: [Beehive Geyser Eruption Sept. 20, 2013 -- Yellowstone National Park](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8gLhHzPY5M)
- [V838 Monocerotis "light-echo" images morphed into nice video, but why so few original images?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14660) vid: [Hubble: Timelapse of V838 Monocerotis (2002-2006)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1fvMSs9cps)
- [Did NASA/JPL get "waning" and "waxing" backwards in this video?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33216) vid: [What's Up: September 2019 Skywatching Tips from NASA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssYGxytMV8Y)
- [Why does the eclipse in this video look annular?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14212) vid: [Solar Eclipse | Incredible Footage From Flight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMvTZaqMDx8)

Comment: surprisingly, the video in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/35967/7982 plays already!

Comment: @uhoh Maybe they already turned it on.

Comment: but the links at the bottom of this don't show https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29973/7982

Comment: @uhoh Hmm...strange